# Can't get Inputs from TextInputLayout when coding in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

actualy i'm facing a problem when coding in android studio . I've implemented a form for the user to enter some information , but when trying to retrieve these information using adaquate methods ,i only get empty and can't retrieve them.

This is a sample of my Layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.DetteCreance.AjoutModificationActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/bleue_sky"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="FORMULAIRE DE RENSEIGNEMENT"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- Renseignement de la date -->



    <!-- Cancel button -->



    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/retour"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/yellow"
        android:text="Retour"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.149"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/modePaiement_dialog"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.083" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/enregistrer"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/bleue_sky"
        android:text="Enregistrer"
        android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.833"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/modePaiement_dialog"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.083" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/date_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint=""
        app:counterMaxLength="8"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mhealth_color"
        style="@style/InputStyle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

        <!-- champ de saisi -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/realDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/mhealth_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/date"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:inputType="date"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/facture_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        app:counterMaxLength="30"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mhealth_color"
        style="@style/InputStyle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_dialog">

        <!-- champ de saisi -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/mhealth_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="@string/facture"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/OrdreEnregistrement_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        app:counterMaxLength="30"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mhealth_color"
        style="@style/InputStyle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/facture_dialog">

        <!-- champ de saisi -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/mhealth_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="@string/numero_ordre"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/typeOperation_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusedByDefault="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:hint="@string/type_operation"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mhealth_color"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/OrdreEnregistrement_dialog"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">

        <!-- champ de saisi -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/mhealth_color"
            android:inputType="none"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/montantInitial_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        app:counterMaxLength="30"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mhealth_color"
        style="@style/InputStyle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/typeOperation_dialog">

        <!-- champ de saisi -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/mhealth_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="@string/montant_initial"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/sommeVerse_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        app:counterMaxLength="30"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mhealth_color"
        style="@style/InputStyle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/montantInitial_dialog">

        <!-- champ de saisi -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/mhealth_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="@string/somme_versee"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/modePaiement_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:focusedByDefault="false"
        android:hint="@string/mode_paiement"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mhealth_color"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sommeVerse_dialog"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">

        <!-- champ de saisi -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/mhealth_color"
            android:inputType="none"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/client_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:focusedByDefault="false"
        android:hint="@string/client"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mhealth_color"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/modePaiement_dialog"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">

        <!-- champ de saisi -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/mhealth_color"
            android:inputType="none"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>










</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is how i am trying to retrieve them :

```
//Setting object Transaction
transaction.setDate(binding.realDate.getText().toString());
transaction.setNum_facture(binding.factureDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
if(binding.factureDialog.getEditText().getText().toString().isEmpty()){
    Log.d("info1","there is not facture");
}else{
    Log.d("info1","there is facture");
}
Log.d("TAG!",binding.factureDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
transaction.setMontant_initial(binding.montantInitialDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
transaction.setSomme_verse(binding.sommeVerseDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
transaction.setNum_ordre_enregistrement(binding.OrdreEnregistrementDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
transaction.setClient(binding.clientDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivityAjoutModificationBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();

        //Initializing spinners
        AppDatabase appDatabase;
        appDatabase=AppDatabase.getDbIntance(this);
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
        List<String> TypeOperation=new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> ModePaiement=new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> client_list=new ArrayList<>();

        if(TypeOperation.isEmpty())
        {
            TypeOperation.add("Créance");
            TypeOperation.add("Dette");
            TypeOperation.add("Versement");
        }else{
            TypeOperation.clear();
        }


        if(ModePaiement.isEmpty()){
            ModePaiement.add("Chèque");
            ModePaiement.add("Espèces");
        }else{
            ModePaiement.clear();
        }

        if(client_list.isEmpty()){
            client_list.add("CSPS du l'EST");
            client_list.add("CSPS du l'OUEST");
            client_list.add("CSPS du NORD");
            client_list.add("CSPS du SUD");
        }else{
            client_list.clear();
        }

        //Liste du Mode de paiement
        ArrayAdapter<String> mode_paiement_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item,ModePaiement);
        MaterialAutoCompleteTextView mode_paiement_autoCompleteTextView = (MaterialAutoCompleteTextView) binding.modePaiementDialog.getEditText();
        assert mode_paiement_autoCompleteTextView != null;
        mode_paiement_autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(mode_paiement_adapter );
        //Liste de Type d'operation
        ArrayAdapter<String> type_operation_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item,TypeOperation);
        MaterialAutoCompleteTextView type_operation_autoCompleteTextView = (MaterialAutoCompleteTextView)binding.typeOperationDialog.getEditText();
        assert type_operation_autoCompleteTextView != null;
        type_operation_autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(type_operation_adapter);
        //Liste des clients
        ArrayAdapter<String> client_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item,client_list);
        MaterialAutoCompleteTextView client_autoCompleteTextView = (MaterialAutoCompleteTextView)binding.clientDialog.getEditText();
        assert client_autoCompleteTextView != null;
        client_autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(client_adapter);

        //Setting object Transaction
        transaction.setDate(binding.realDate.getText().toString());
        transaction.setNum_facture(binding.factureDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
        if(binding.factureDialog.getEditText().getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            Log.d("info1","there is not facture");
        }else{
            Log.d("info1","there is facture");
        }
        Log.d("TAG!",binding.factureDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
        transaction.setMontant_initial(binding.montantInitialDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
        transaction.setSomme_verse(binding.sommeVerseDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
        transaction.setNum_ordre_enregistrement(binding.OrdreEnregistrementDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
        transaction.setClient(binding.clientDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());

        //Insérer transaction dans BD
        binding.enregistrer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                appDatabase.transactionDao().insert(transaction);

            }
        });

        //Picking date
        final Calendar myCalendar= Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener select_date = (v, year, month, day) -> {
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
            String myFormat="yy/MM/dd";
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.FRENCH);
            binding.realDate.setText(dateFormat.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

        };
        binding.realDate.setOnClickListener(v -> new DatePickerDialog(this,select_date,myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show());

        binding.retour.setOnClickListener(v->{
                finish();
                }
                );

        setContentView(view);
    }


package com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx.main.DetteCreance;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
import com.ticanalyse.mheath.bf.R;
import com.ticanalyse.mheath.bf.databinding.ActivityAjoutModificationBinding;
import com.ticanalyse.mheath.bf.databinding.FragmentAjoutModificationDialogBinding;
import com.ticanalyse.mheath.bf.db.AppDatabase;
import com.ticanalyse.mheath.bf.db.entities.Transaction;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class AjoutModificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityAjoutModificationBinding binding;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivityAjoutModificationBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        //Initializing spinners
        AppDatabase appDatabase;
        appDatabase=AppDatabase.getDbIntance(this);
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
        List<String> TypeOperation=new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> ModePaiement=new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> client_list=new ArrayList<>();

        if(TypeOperation.isEmpty())
        {
            TypeOperation.add("Créance");
            TypeOperation.add("Dette");
            TypeOperation.add("Versement");
        }else{
            TypeOperation.clear();
        }


        if(ModePaiement.isEmpty()){
            ModePaiement.add("Chèque");
            ModePaiement.add("Espèces");
        }else{
            ModePaiement.clear();
        }

        if(client_list.isEmpty()){
            client_list.add("CSPS du l'EST");
            client_list.add("CSPS du l'OUEST");
            client_list.add("CSPS du NORD");
            client_list.add("CSPS du SUD");
        }else{
            client_list.clear();
        }

        //Liste du Mode de paiement
        ArrayAdapter<String> mode_paiement_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item,ModePaiement);
        MaterialAutoCompleteTextView mode_paiement_autoCompleteTextView = (MaterialAutoCompleteTextView) binding.modePaiementDialog.getEditText();
        assert mode_paiement_autoCompleteTextView != null;
        mode_paiement_autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(mode_paiement_adapter );
        //Liste de Type d'operation
        ArrayAdapter<String> type_operation_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item,TypeOperation);
        MaterialAutoCompleteTextView type_operation_autoCompleteTextView = (MaterialAutoCompleteTextView)binding.typeOperationDialog.getEditText();
        assert type_operation_autoCompleteTextView != null;
        type_operation_autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(type_operation_adapter);
        //Liste des clients
        ArrayAdapter<String> client_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item,client_list);
        MaterialAutoCompleteTextView client_autoCompleteTextView = (MaterialAutoCompleteTextView)binding.clientDialog.getEditText();
        assert client_autoCompleteTextView != null;
        client_autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(client_adapter);


        //Setting object Transaction
        transaction.setDate(binding.realDate.getText().toString());
        transaction.setNum_facture(binding.factureDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
        if(binding.factureDialog.getEditText().getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            Log.d("info1","there is not facture");
        }else{
            Log.d("info1","there is facture");
        }
        Log.d("TAG!",binding.factureDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
        transaction.setMontant_initial(binding.montantInitialDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
        transaction.setSomme_verse(binding.sommeVerseDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
        transaction.setNum_ordre_enregistrement(binding.OrdreEnregistrementDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
        transaction.setClient(binding.clientDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());

        //Insérer transaction dans BD
        binding.enregistrer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                appDatabase.transactionDao().insert(transaction);

            }
        });

        //Picking date
        final Calendar myCalendar= Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener select_date = (v, year, month, day) -> {
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
            String myFormat="yy/MM/dd";
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.FRENCH);
            binding.realDate.setText(dateFormat.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

        };
        binding.realDate.setOnClickListener(v -> new DatePickerDialog(this,select_date,myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show());

        binding.retour.setOnClickListener(v->{
                    finish();
                }
        );
    }

}
```

When i check the different fields of the instance :"transaction" , it returns me an empty object . Could you help me please ?

Comment: Show your `onCreate` where you reference your views

Answer (score 1):

Remove all of these that are outside of your `onCreate`

```
//Setting object Transaction
transaction.setDate(binding.realDate.getText().toString());
transaction.setNum_facture(binding.factureDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
if(binding.factureDialog.getEditText().getText().toString().isEmpty()){
    Log.d("info1","there is not facture");
}else{
    Log.d("info1","there is facture");
}
Log.d("TAG!",binding.factureDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
transaction.setMontant_initial(binding.montantInitialDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
transaction.setSomme_verse(binding.sommeVerseDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
transaction.setNum_ordre_enregistrement(binding.OrdreEnregistrementDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
transaction.setClient(binding.clientDialog.getEditText().getText().toString());
```

You are referencing all your xml views **BEFORE** you set your view root in your activity.

So scroll down at the bottom most part of your `onCreate` then remove this

```
  setContentView(view);
```

and put it in the place of

```
  View view = binding.getRoot();
```

making your `onCreate` look like this.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding=ActivityAjoutModificationBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.root)
```

Comment: it still does'nt work

Comment: @PatrickRenaud at this point I'm not sure anymore. Strip down your codes down to the bare minimum and show your entire activity. And also, like I mentioned on my first deleted answer, `factureDialog` doesn't exist in the `xml` you posted

Comment: i've edited added the entire activity ... factureDialog exists .. Just scroll down and you will see

Comment: I meant the `xml` code you posted, I copy and pasted it into my own xml file, I searched `factureDialog` `OrdreEnregistrementDialog` `sommeVerseDialog`, they aren't there.

Comment: in the xml for facture_dialog , when trying to access it by calling binding , it proposes factureDialog . i think  android studio has refactored it